# Chromium extension: javascript not executed

Tags: google-chrome

Making a simple plugin , which executes javascript when a page is loaded , and I want to execute different javascript on different page

But the following code wasn't working as expected , no "alert" was triggered:

`background.html`:

```
<html><body>
<script>
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(
  function(details) {
    alert (details.url);
  },
  {
      urls: ["*"],
      types: ["main_frame"]
  },
  []
);
</script>
</body></html>
```

`manifest.json`:

```
{
  "name": "JS",
  "background_page": "background.html",
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "*"
  ],
  "version":"0.10"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alerts and console.log made from the background page of an extension simply aren't visible on the general pages.

If you want to see them, you have to open the background page : Go to the extensions settings page (menu tools/extensions) and click the "background.html" link below the name of your extension.

In your case it may be better, during development phase, to simply add the console.log and alerts in the content scripts (i.e. not the background page). So you can read them without opening the background page.

EDIT : as requested, an extension that will simply alert the location :

main.js :

```
alert(document.location.href);
```

manifest.json :

```
{
    "name": "Any name",
    "version": "3.3",
    "background_page": "background.html",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://*/*"],
            "all_frames" : true,
            "run_at" : "document_end",
            "js": [
                "main.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Yes I tested it. And yes it's as painful as it sounds. You should use `console.log` instead of `alert` during your dev.

Comment: Sorry , no , i wanted the code to be executed on every page , and the code should dwell in background.html , am I wrong ?

Comment: I'm not sure of what you want, so maybe my comment won't be useful but if you simply want to execute a script on every page you may simply add it in a content script, which then may do something different depending on the location, as in [this main.js](https://github.com/Canop/braldop/blob/master/chrome/braldop/ext_main.js).

Comment: ok , so think this as a auto login script for some website , that's closer .. can you provide a minimal example here ?

Comment: A minimal example for a complete auto login ? No, that would be too dependent on the specific sites. But I can confirm you can do it with content scripts as you can inject code in the pages to read and change their content (I inject jquery as a content script to help with this task), open links, store login data in localstorage, and so on (read my code I linked above if you want to see what's possible along those lines).

Comment: Not for autologin .. just for executing a "alert()"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11875/discussion-between-dystroy-and-warl0ck)